# XMLHttpRequest charset

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest

First my english not good so sorry about it..,
im trying to post hebrew with this function.
and i dont know how can i define encoding (Windows-1255 for example).

```
function send(){
   var sendto = '../includes/chat_post.php?usermsg=' + document.getElementById('usermsg').value + '&fullname=' + document.getElementById('fullname').value + '&submitmsg=' + document.getElementById('submitmsg').value;
   if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.open("POST",sendto,false);
      xmlhttp.send(null);
      scroll_downy();
   }
   else{
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      xmlhttp.open("POST",sendto,false);
      xmlhttp.send();
      scroll_downy();
   }
   var error = '';
   if(error == ''){
      document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = '';
      showmessages();
      scroll_downy();
   }
   else{
      document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = error;
   }
}
```

Any ideas to solve it ? thanks for everybody

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, the default charset for XMLHttpRequest is utf-8, which you can (and should) use to send Hebrew. However, you can set the charset encoding yourself with:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
```

Comment: I tried it but in google chrome its work and in opera its write me "×©×" it need to be "ùí"

Comment: Is that what you're getting on the server, or back in the browser?